# App crashes when it receives a SMS in the Broadcast Receiver class

Tags: android

I have a broadcast receiver class in my app. It should start playing audio on receiving a message but my app crashes as soon as it receives the message.

#### SmsReceiver.java

---

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";
    MediaPlayer mPlay = new MediaPlayer();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get the SMS map from Intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String body = "";
        Context a = null;
        mPlay.create(a, R.raw.sample);
        if (extras != null) {
            // Get received SMS array
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get(SMS_EXTRA_NAME);

            for (int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i) {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);

                body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
                if (body.equalsIgnoreCase("xxx")) {
                    mPlay.start();
                    this.abortBroadcast();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onKeyDown() {
        mPlay.stop();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        mPlay.stop();
    }
}
```

#### Logcat

---

```
I/PackageManager(  174): /data/app/com.test.example-2.apk changed; collecting certs
I/PackageManager(  174): /data/app/com.test.example-2.apk changed; unpacking
I/ActivityManager(  174): Start proc com.test.example for broadcast com.test.example/.SmsReceiver: pid=1043 uid=10083 gids={}
E/AndroidRuntime( 1043): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.test.example.SmsReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1043):    at com.test.example.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:20)
I/ActivityManager(  174): Process com.test.example (pid 1043) has died.
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.test.example"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
      android:name=".SmsReceiver"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHANGE

```
Context a = null;
mPlay.create(a, R.raw.sample);
```

TO be

```
mPlay.create(context, R.raw.sample);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.test.example.SmsReceiver:     java.lang.NullPointerException
  E/AndroidRuntime( 1043):  at com.test.example.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:20)
```

There's a NullPointer there. What happens in line 20 of SmsReceiver.java?

Is there any possibility that mPlay can be null?

Comment: Line 19 :  Context a = null;
Line 20 : mPlay.create(a, R.raw.scream);

Answer (score 0):

Your context is null, see:

```
Context a = null;
mPlay.create(a, R.raw.sample);
```

You should do:

```
Context a = context;
mPlay.create(a, R.raw.sample);
```

Hugs.

Answer (score 0):

The first potential problem I see is here

```
Context a = null;
```

this should be

```
Context a = context;
```

You have a `context` passed in to it so there's no reason to make it `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using some object reference without initializing on line 20 in SmsReceiver.java. Initialize that.

```
mPlay.create(a, R.raw.sample);
```

In the above line you are passing a as null. Make it

```
mPlay.create(this, R.raw.sample);
```